# What are some (beginner) introductory books about Technical Analysis of Stocks?

Tags: investing, starting-out-investing, technical-analysis, reference-material

I read Technical Analysis for Dummies...and am looking for a more detailed insight into the topic.

Comment: @Ganesh: Why close this when it is very similar to [this question](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/15608/recommendation-for-learning-fundamental-analysis) and yet that question has JoeTaxpayer answering it (and not closing it). It seems this question is not a produce or service recommendation, but a reference request (which should be valid on ANY *.SE site).

Comment: @Peter It's asking for a book recommendation, which I think comes under product recommendation. These kinds of questions definitely get closed on StackOverflow (see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943139/http-book-recommendation) though the close reason there does explicitly mention 'book'. In practice my attention was drawn to this one because it attracted a spam flag for the most recent answer, which highlights one of the difficulties of recommendation requests - it's hard to distinguish between advertising and a genuine recommendation.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam : Thanks for the response! I disagree, but there you are. :-)

Answer (score 2):

The book [Come into my trading room](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471225347) is a great mix of technical analysis and trading psychology.

Comment: Is it a beginner book in your opinion?

Comment: I think so. it doesn't go into any crazy mathematical models. Just how to apply the most basic technical indicators but also how to manage risk.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you're into value investment or not, Ben Graham's [The Intelligent Investor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0060555661) is a must-read, though it focuses less on technical aspect of investment, but emphasizing on investor's discipline and investment framework.

If you're looking for an in-depth (non-introductory) technical analysis, I'd recommend you another Ben's masterpiece - [The Security Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0071592539).

Comment: The Intelligent Investor was not an easy read for me the first time. I am having a second go. I will hold off on the other book for now since it is not a beginner one

Comment: Good to hear that you own the book, take your time to enjoy it :)

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with the user above about John J. Murphy. Here are my favorites below:

- [Trend Trading for a Living](http://www.recordpricebreakout.com/book-review-trend-trading-for-a-living-by-dr-thomas-k-carr/) by Dr. Thomas Carr - Click the link for a review
- Technical Analysis of the Financial Markets Book and Study Guide - John J. Murphy
- Japanese Candlestick Charting Techniques - Steve Nison

Answer (score 0):

"Technical Analysis of the Futures Markets: A Comprehensive Guide to Trading Methods and Applications" by John Murphy is a classic written in a easy to understand style, and is not only for Futures. Most of the technical indicators discussed apply to stocks as well.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend "The 1-Day Technical Analysis Expert Guide" from the Amazon website or from the author's website:
Amazon Kindle Edition: [http://www.amazon.com/dp/B017FYKDBY/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B017FYKDBY) 
PDF Edition: http://www.etradingpicks.com/product/the-1-day-technical-analysis-expert-guide/